No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg' in Django/Docker
I run my Django code in Docker. I run transcription software that requires ffmpeg to function. However I've been getting the error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg' whenever I try to run my code.
Here's my views.py:
def initiate_transcription(request, session_id):
    ...
                with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                    path_string = f.name
                    transcript = transcribe_file(path_string,audio_language, output_file_type)

   ...

Here's my Dockerfile:
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bullseye

# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV COLUMNS 80

#install Debian and other dependencies that are required to run python apps(eg. git, python-magic).
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
 nano python3-pip gettext chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev \
 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev  libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev\
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmagic-dev
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg


# Set working directory for Docker image
WORKDIR /code/

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project
COPY . .

I've searched online for possible solutions but have not been able to find anything similar to my problem

Does your $PATH environment variable include /usr/bin? Can you post the output of print(os.environ['PATH')) ?

@NickODell Yes it does contain /usr/bin. C:\\Program Files\Git\usr\bin. The result of print(os.environs['PATH']) is /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
(I ran the print statement from settings.py, if that matters)

try it with this line in your Dockerfile:
pip3 install --no-cache-dir ffmpeg-python

you may also need:
apt-get install -y ffmpeg


Do you mean like this?
Dockerfile:
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg```

yes - let me know how that works! - i would run the ffmpeg install before the pip install

Hi. I simply deleted my old builds and then rebuilt and it worked.
